# htaccess url rewrite (db access)?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a web page with the following parameters.

http://www.somesite.com/community_details.php?comm_id=233&region_id=2&city_id=40

I would like it changed to this

http://www.somesite.com/virginia/fairfax/some_community/

How do I call db to return region, city, community for a url rewrite in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly efficient, but you CAN use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to use an external txt/dbm/program to let mod_rewrite do lookups and rewrite based on the results.

```
RewriteMap pretty-community prg:/path/to/some/shell/script

RewriteRule community_details.php?(.*) ${pretty-community:$1}
```

The captured query string from the community_details.php script would be passed to the specified external script on its stdin, and the script replies with the rewritten url via its stdout.

Note that the script is started ONCE when Apache first fires up, and then essentially runs in daemon mode, communicating with Apache for every rewrite performed. Since PHP isn't particularly suitable for writing daemons, you might want to do this program in some other language.

Comment: Mark, I did this

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteMap examplemap txt:/var/www/html/mysite/key_pair.txt
RewriteRule community_details.php?(.*) ${examplemap:$1}

now i get a page not found.

this is a sample of the key-pair text

252 Georgia/Kennesaw/Landings-at-Kennesaw-Mountain

Comment: Sorry is wasn't page not found it is this.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: 500 internal server errors get explanatory reasons logged in the server's error log. Getting a rewritemap working is tricky, and you'll probably have to play with it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I think; you can't

If your link is http://www.somesite.com/virginia/fairfax/some_community/

you could change it with htacces as http://www.somesite.com/community_details.php?comm_code=samo_community&region_code=virginia&city_code=fairfax

and take id of codes from database to use in php.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this is a good start:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

You create a regex for your pattern, then write an external Perl/PHP whatever script that implements a hash lookup against a MySQL table and returns it to Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite easy.
just route ALL virtual requests to php scritp which will query a database.

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and you will have requested path in $_GET['request'].

split it up using explode and get your parameters from db.

Comment: that hardly returns the DB values back to .htaccess "for url rewrite", right

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

What you can do is have `community_details.php` do the database lookup, then call `die(header("Location: blahblahblah"));`. But then you would have to process that back using .htaccess and everything else, so it might be easier to just not do that at all - depends on how important such URLs are to you.

Comment: ok, but how do i write my .htaccess to accept parameters to view correct page..so it understands 233 is some_community  region_id of 2 is virginia and city_id of 40 equal fairfax