# MVC htaccess redirect rule if page does not exist

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.3

I have a few URLs such as 
http://sitename.com/recipes/234 
//sitename.com/recipes/235 
//sitename.com/recipes/236 

The URL routes are set in this way : 
//sitename.com/controller/action/ID

I need to write an htaccess rule that will do a 301 redirect to 
http://sitename.com/recipes 
 **if the item does not exist and cake throws a 404 error** .

I have tried this in core PHP and it works fine . But I am finding it difficult to do the same in an MVC environment . I want to implement it on cakephp framework .

I tried using the following code

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What framework are you using? It's not clear from the tags.

Comment: I want to implement it on cakephp framework .

Comment: Whether a recipe exists or not should be being handled by your app rather than .htaccess so your redirect needs handling in your app's controller. How have you setup your routes?

Comment: Yes , I absolutely understand that . But I need to know if it is possible doing it via the htaccess file .
Instead of showing the 404 status code I need to redirect it to /recipes page .

Comment: It simply cannot be done via `.htaccess` (only), the Apache environment is not aware of what exists, or doesn't exist in your database, this problem _must_ be resolved at a different level, like PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956072/htaccess-url-rewrite-db-access

Comment: @ndm , what about the following code ?  
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L]  

The first two conditions do check if a file exists or not right ? Also I am not checking if anything exists in the DATABASE , only if a page is not found , redirect .

Comment: They check whether the requested path points to an actual file or directory in the filesystem. If you're not talking about checking the database, then you should elaborate on that in your question, and mention what _exactly_ a "page" in your application represents, because the URLs look as if the numerical values are IDs.

Comment: So, instead of providing details, you're handing out insults? OK, here we go... If _you_ would know CakePHP, then you'd know that nobody can definitely tell what a URL points to, without knowing the underlying connected routes. You'd also know that default baked RUD actions throw 404 exceptions when a database record isn't found (being it queried directly, or indirectly via pagination). So again, please specify what _exactly_ pages in your application are, and under which circumstances a 404 is being triggered. ps, this is going to be my last comment on this subject

Comment: @ndm , I apologize if any statement made is offensive to you . Please understand I have no intentions on insulting anyone here . I didnt imply that you do not know cakephp (its so very obvious from your profile) . What I meant was , considering how cakephp works , url generation is dynamic which is exactly what you have explained further in your comment . I just wished to know if it was possible to still achieve this .

Answer (score 2):

For MVC, in your Recipes controller view method, for example, you could use following code:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    // ....

    $recipe = $this->Recipe->findById($id);

    if (!$recipe) {
        // Not found flash error message
        return $this->redirect(
            array('action' => 'index'),// -> Recipes index page
            301
        );
    }

    // ....
}
```

See docs [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect).

Comment: Hi , like I said I do not want to do any changes in the controllers or routes .I need to know if this can be done via htaccess rules .